# What is a good book with authoritative histories of individual RAF bases?

Tags: military, great-britain

I write a lot about RAF radar systems. It is common to refer to the base where it was first built, like RAF Bard Hill. However, I find it very difficult to find anything about Bard Hill, what does exist on the web is highly fractured.

Does anyone know of a good source for such information? I'm not looking for too much detail, something more along the lines of a "who's who in the RAF bases", perhaps a paragraph or two per base, with the main criterion being completeness in terms of all the bases being there.